# Where is the comment?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-answers

I was looking [a deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51022/can-i-run-an-intranet-version-of-stack-overflow/110426#110426) (the link is for 10k users or moderators) for which there was a comment.

[image: screenshot]

When I clicked on "show 1 more comment," the comment was not shown.

[image: screenshot]

Who has stolen the comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ♦ "show deleted comments" button reports that one comment was deleted by the user (nico) about 1 minute after being created. It is entirely possible that this is simply a denormalized counter that was misreporting as "1" instead of "0" (for the number of active comments) - perhaps some old glitch due to the post being deleted.

Edit: there is a second comment that was deleted more recently (the comment was obsolete) - I'll check if there is a glith in the admin tools (i.e. not resetting that counter)

Comment: Wait, deleted comments aren't actually deleted *either*? You actually do delete chat messages though, right? Right?

Answer (score 0):

Isn’t there a possibility of user may delete the comment at the same time where you try to view that. If so you might see there is a comment which actually not there.

Comment: The answer is deleted (hence the grey background) I don't think you can do anything on deleted posts - including delete comments.

Comment: Even if it were possible to delete comments on deleted answers, I refreshed the page, closed the tab I was using to view the question, opened a new tab to watch the question on that tab; still, I am said there is a comment, but that comment is not shown.

Comment: I was able to delete a comment I posted for an answer that has been converted in a comment, after the answer was deleted. This means it is possible to delete comments from deleted answers, if you are the 10k user who wrote it; I guess that moderators can also delete comments from deleted answers.